# Problem about Deploying nextjs app on IIS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am new in using nextjs SSR framework of React js. I want to publish my app on iis. but I can not. here is the list of steps that i took to deploy my app.

1- i build my app useing npm run build command.

2 - i use server.js file that is mentioned below :

```js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

3- i use web.config file taht is mentioned beolow

```js
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

now when i add new website in the iis and set the physical path to the folder , i do not know which files would be in the folder.
i really appreciate it if someone could help me to overcome this challenge.
bests

Comment: If you switch to HttpPlatformHandler, you can see the simplified steps, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use IIS to serve next.js app. The next.js has build in server.

Also you don't need to use this `server.js` file at all. You can just run `npm run start` which will run perviously built project (with `npm run build`) in production mode.

If you still wanna use IIS you can but only as a reverse proxy and but not as a server.

Check the official docs on how to use next.js in prod: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-cli#production

Comment: thanks for your comment. but i think that you miss understand the problem. the issue that i face is about deploying the nextjs app on iis server not about starting the application.

Comment: It is just not feasible to require NPM to be installed on a production server. So, asking others to run `npm run xxx` isn't the right way.